# Application of Plancherel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I try to see how

\begin{align*}
3^{-n} \sum_{Y \in \mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z}}|g(Y)-3^{m-n}\sum_{Y' \in \mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z} |Y' = Y \mod 3^m} g(Y')|^2 = \\ = \sum_{\xi \in \mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z} : 3^{n-m} \nmid \xi}|\sum_{Y \in \mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z}} g(Y)e^{-2 \pi i \xi Y / 3^n}  |^2
\end{align*}

follows from Plancherel's theorem, which at least I know only in the form
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \bar{g(x)} dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f(\xi)} \bar{\hat{g(\xi)}} d \xi.
\end{align*}
Having only little experience in harmonic analysis, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Here's a hint: In addition to Plancherel's theorem for the real line, which you state, there's a version for functions on cyclic groups. This can be thought of in terms of the discrete Fourier transform, in case that's more familiar. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_Plancherel_theorem_and_Parseval's_theorem